# Config other platform in Firebase dynamic link for Android

Tags: android, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to set other link when user open DynamicLink on desktop web browser.
There are DynamicLinkOtherPlatformParameters for iOS, but not Android. 
How can I get that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your link in android by using "ofl" parameter.

https://{page_link}/?isi={app_store_id}&ibi={ios_bundle_identifier}&ofl={firbase_deep_link+other_parameters}&imv={ios_min_version}&amv={android_min_version}&apn={android_package_name}&link={firebase_dynamic_link}